# Log4j2 tomcat configuration issue during Spring startup

Tags: java, spring, logging, tomcat7, log4j2

I am having an issue with my recently upgraded log4j. Moved to log4j2, and I am seeing outputs from Spring attaching URL path handlers at the INFO level. However I am setting my root logger to error.

Here is the configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_DIR">logs</Property>
        <Property name="ARCHIVE">${LOG_DIR}</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_PREFIX">logname-</Property>
        <Property name="FILE_PATTERN">%d{ISO8601}\t%r\t%t\t%-5p\t%c{1}\t%m%n</Property>
        <Property name="CONSOLE_PATTERN">[%d{ISO8601}|%-5p|%c{1}|%M|%L] %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <File name="FILE" fileName="logname.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${FILEPATTERN}" />
        </File>
        <RollingFile name="fileWriter" fileName="${LOG_DIR}/${LOG_PREFIX}.log" filePattern="${ARCHIVE}/${LOG_PREFIX}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.log" immediateFlush="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${FILE_PATTERN}" />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${CONSOLE_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
        <Async name="Async-File">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
        </Async>
        <Async name="Async-Console">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root>
            <AppenderRef ref="Async-Console" level="error" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Async-File" level="error" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And the tomcat output on startup

```
Nov 01, 2015 5:19:34 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/universal/applyTemplate/] onto handler 'RESTTemplate'
```

There are a couple hundred lines of this startup but I figured one would be sufficient. Is the ROOT logger not being overridden in this case?

Tomcat version is 7.55 as well.

Answer (score 0):

The output doesn't match the pattern your configuration must not be in use. Did you add log4j-web to your application? Did you follow the instructions at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html?

Comment: Yes, I have added log4j-web to my application. I have tried the steps in the linked provided with no avail

Comment: The answer was adding the log4j jlc jar to the dependencies.